# Trimforce on third party SSD disables keyboard and touchpad

Tags: keyboard, ssd, trackpad, trim

- Specs: [MBP 15" Mid 2010 i7 8gb ram](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp582?locale=en_US)
- SSD: [Sandisk PLUS 240GB SATA3](https://www.sandisk.com.au/home/ssd/ssd-plus)
- OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.1

Brand new SSD. Fresh install of macOS Sierra with the latest update 10.12.1.

When using `sudo trimforce enable` it enables successfully and reboots the machine. After the reboot during the first 20-30 seconds built-in keyboard and trackpad stop responding and they never recover back. The only fix is to disable trim: `sudo trimforce disable`.

When trim is disabled everything works absolutely fine - no issues with keyboard nor trackpad.

What could cause such behaviour?

Answer (score -1):

a. Trim is not really necessary on modern SSD's. GarbageCollection works pefectly fast when there is enough free space, say 20% or more.
b. Do not use Trim when the SSD has not a modern Marvel controller (never install trim on a SSD with Sandforce controller.
The new Sandisk SSDs have a Marvel controller, I do not know what controller is in the Sandisk Plus.

Comment: Why would then TRIM be enabled on the new 2016 original Apple SSD's?